# Erro ao desserializar json

Tags: c#, json

Estou com um pequeno problema ao `deserializar` meu `json`, e não sei porque

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        Uri BaseAdress = Services.Token.BaseAdress;
        string strToken = Services.Token.strToken;
        List<FormaPagamentoFinModel> ListaAmbientes;
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = BaseAdress;
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", strToken);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("Application/Json"));
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("/api/FormaPagamentoFin/findAll"))
            {

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string resul = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ListaAmbientes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FormaPagamentoFinModel>>(resul);
            }
        }
        return View(ListaAmbientes);
    }
```

A minha variável `resul` recebe os dados normal, mas ao `Deserializar` ele me retorna tudo `null`, ele me retorna o `count` corretamente, mas as variáveis tudo com valor null

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Método FindAll na API:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("findAll")]
    public HttpResponseMessage findAll()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var ambientes = bdprincipalEntities.forma_pagamento_fin.Select(
                    x => new {
                        Fpg_codigo = x.Fpf_codigo,
                        Fpg_descricao = x.Fpf_descricao,
                        Fpg_quantidade = x.Fpf_quantidade,
                        Fpg_situacao = x.Fpf_situacao.Equals("A") ? "ATIVO" : "DESATIVADO"
                    }).ToList();
            result.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ambientes));
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: O model `FormaPagamentoFinModel` é o mesmo retornado pelo método `/api/FormaPagamentoFin/findAll` ? Como é esse método `FindAll`?

Comment: Vou colocar na pergunta, desculpe

Comment: Nossa, me toquei do erro só agora, Eu estou passando errado na api

Comment: Poste uma resposta que eu aceito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No código postado, a definição do objeto no método `FindAll` está diferente do objeto `FormaPagamentoFinModel`.

Um exemplo seria trocar de `Fpg_codigo`para `Fpf_codigo` assim como as outras propriedades com nomes diferentes.